# How to get rid of (base) environment prefix shown in terminal

Tags: python, anaconda, pipenv

I have quite some problems using python on my Mac. I need different versions from 3.5 to 3.7 and multiple packages for data science. Due to various instructions on the web I ended up installing python 3.6 itself, anaconda, pipenv and maybe more stuff I can't even remember.

I suppose there is no other way to eliminate this mess than to format everything and start over. Currently my terminal is showing some sort of prefix for the environment in the terminal. Something like:

```
(base) user@machine:~$:
```

How can I at least get rid of this environment prefix? It appeared after installing pipenv, which seems to have taken over my previous anaconda environments. I fear those vanish to when uninstalling pipenv.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `deactivate` command alone will get you out of the currently activated virtual environment.

```
(base) user@machine:~$:
(base) user@machine:~$: deactivate
user@machine:~$:
```

As far as I know, this works across all operating systems.

Comment: "conda deactivate" did the trick. But when opening a new terminal it's back again. The base environment is the default environment. So I guess this one will always be active when starting a new terminal, wouldn't it?

Comment: Hmm strange. Do you have a file within that directory called `environment.yml`?

Comment: I can open the terminal in every folder and this happens. Therefor I guess it has to be something global. Couldn't find a environment.yml in /etc.

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem: Anaconda edited the .bash_profile which gets executed on the mac for each new terminal. I deleted the anaconda entry and the base prefix is gone.

Answer (score 3):

Also, for anyone that is using **zsh** and Anaconda.

You can remove the entry Anaconda makes from the `~/.zshrc` file in addition to the `conda deactivate`

Answer (score 2):

Conda can be configured with command `conda config`

This command will remove message about the current environment:
`conda config --set changeps1 no`

This command will add messages about the current environment:
`conda config --set changeps1 yes`

https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#change-command-prompt

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

`conda config --set auto_activate_base false`
is an easy way to fix this

For anyone that's still confused about this:

What happens is that **Conda** automatically activates the `base` environment by default each time you open the terminal. This changes the current Python interpreter to the one in `base`, so you can use the packages you have installed there. This (in my opinion) is annoying and confusing for new users. For the people that install **Conda** for use within an IDE, they won't be using the environment that much via the terminal anyway. Of course, you could just do `conda deactivate` each time.

A more sensible solution is to disable the auto-activation on startup:
`conda config --set auto_activate_base false`

You can still use the environment whenever you need it by doing
`conda activate`